# Set the Value of a variable into an EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm new to Android studio.

I have 
two EditText (Text boxes) and 
one button.

When a user inputs a number into EditText1 and Press the Button, the value of the EditText1 should multiply by 2 and appear in the EditText2.

How can I make this Happen.

This is what i have

I'm only able to Toast the value

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public void convert(View view){
    EditText textbox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textbox1);
    Double nairaAmount = Double.parseDouble(textbox.getText().toString());
    Double cediAmount =nairaAmount*2;

    Log.i("textbox1",cediAmount.toString());

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GHc"+ cediAmount.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

Comment: Hey, can you show the code you have attempted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try this put this code in your oncreate method()**

```
final EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
final EditText editText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);

Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    //set validation on button click like this
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                int ans= Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString().trim());
               ans=ans*ans;
                editText2.setText(ans+"");
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: `Toast.makeText(getActivity()` did not work for me so I used 
`Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()`